# How to flatten array results into one distinct array in Neo4j

Tags: arrays, neo4j

I'm trying to flatten an array property into one array with a Neo4j query.

Unflattened looks like this:

```
MATCH (Parent)-[:Has]-(c:Child)
RETURN c.myIntArray
```

I have found the reduce function

```
RETURN REDUCE(output = [], s IN c.myIntArray | output + s) AS flat
```

I'm struggling with the syntax, I think I need to pass all the arrays into this function, the above only passes each rows one at a time.

My end goal to to produce one array of distinct ints.

Answer (score 0):

As always as soon as you post here you find the answer.

I'll put it here in case anyone else finds it useful.

```
MATCH (Parent)-[:Has]-(c:Child)
WHERE c.myIntArray IS NOT NULL 
WITH COLLECT(c.myIntArray) AS myInts
WITH REDUCE(output = [], i IN myInts| output + i) AS flat
UNWIND flat AS all
RETURN DISTINCT all
```

It's not very fast though.